# Selenium can't fill input field

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Are there cases Selenium just won't work?
for example, let's say I want to go to Bank Of America and set some online value.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bankofamerica.com/");

                var js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                var title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByName('id').setAttribute('value','Some ID...')");
                Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

get an exception of :

```
{"unknown error: undefined is not a function\n  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"}
```

Comment: sorry - c#. Thing is I want to automate stuff on 3rd party sites but seems like there is some security blocking me?

Comment: Have you read the Selenium documentation? This is not how Selenium is supposed to be used, you are just using it to execute JS.

Comment: for inputing any text use sendKeys function. And for the part of setting attrib, i tried with getElementById...it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the page is not loaded at the moment you are trying to access the field to input the value.
Set a conditioner to wait until the page is loaded

Try something like that

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```